# How to create asynchronous message in sequence diagram using Enterprise Architect 15.0?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram, asynchronous-method-call

How can I change the type of the message in a sequence diagram from synchronous to asynchronous while modelling it with Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect 15.0?

I recall in the past it was just either an obvious option in the context menu or property or both. The [official Sparx documentation](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/sequencemessage.html) (for current 15.1 version) suggests the same:

> ## Create a Message on a Sequence diagram
>
> **Option: Synch**
>   Click on the drop-down arrow and select 'Synchronous' or 'Asynchronous' as appropriate.
>   The value 'Synchronous' disables the 'Kind' field; synchronous Messages are always Calls.

Yet I can neither see it in the context menu nor in the Properties anymore.

[image: context menu] [image]

The only way I managed to do it is by changing the default message type for the sequence diagram, but changing it each time to set an asynchronous message (and changing back to synchronous) seems an overkill.

Neither Google search nor search on SO gave me any reasonable suggestions. It has allowed me to find a workaround mentioned above only.

Note, I am not talking here about IsReturn, this works fine. I am talking about an asynchronous message, represented with a solid line and an open arrow.

Comment: The EA-WHIM syndrome (WHere Is my Menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather simple. You are not showing the whole properties view.

If you drag the bottom a bit further down you'll see the option to set the synchronous/asynchronous

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought of resizing. Well, anyway it's a bug to me. There should be a possibility to scroll the window but there is no scrolling bar nor does the mouse wheel work. I'm pretty sure in the older version I was using (11 I guess) an entirely new window with properties was popping out. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Ister Yes, in v.11 you had a popup window that automatically showed you all contents. EA has been moving away from popup an towards docked properties windows for a while now, and that works better for some dialogs than for others.